# java.io.FileNotFoundException error message

Tags: java

I have a simple program that checks if my file exists.

I've copied the file under my work folder (with my java classes) and in c:.

when calling `new FileInputStream("1.xls")`, the code generats an exception error!

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: 1.xls (Le fichier spécifié est introuvable)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:101)
    at NewMain.main(NewMain.java:25)
```

when calling it with `new FileInputStream("c:\\1.xls")`, it works!

Here is my code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
  // TODO code application logic here
  InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("c:\\1.xls"));
  System.out.print("The file exists");
}
```

Comment: In the first one, you've specified a relative path, so it looks from where it currently is, whereas `c:\\1.xls` is absolute.

Comment: What is your working directory?

Comment: If you are on Windows you need to add your drive letter before your path:
InputStream is = new FileInputStream("C:\\1.xls");

Comment: For first case to be success you 1.xls should be present in parallel to YOURCLASS.class file,if it is not there then your second case code need to implement.

Comment: - yes I'm on windows.
- I've putted my xls file in both of .java and .class files directories and still not working.
- My working directory is C:\NetBeansProjects\TestExcel\src

Comment: it's working now. Look far at the bottom of the thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I've copied the file under my work folder (with my java classes)

This `"1.xls"` is a relative path. When running in development in your IDE (reading from the file system) the path will be relative to the working directory, which is generally the project root. So your file (given that relative path) will have to be in the directly in the project root, the same level as the src

If running from command like and the working directory is the where the class is, and the file is where the class is, then that should also work with the path you're using

> when calling it with new FileInputStream("c:\1.xls"), it works!

Yes it should work. generally absolute paths *should* work

---

**Note:** The fact that you're placing the file where the Java class is, tells me that you want the file to be embedded as a resource to your project. In that case, you *do NOT* want to read it from the file system. You should be reading it in through a url resource stream. You can do so by using `YourClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/path/to/file")` which will return an `InputStream`. So you can do something like

```
InputStream is = YourClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/path/to/file");
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
```

The reason you want to do it this way is that once you have the application in a jar, the path you use reading from the file system will no longer be valid, so it must be read via the classpath. With the code above, the `/` is important, as it will bring you to the root of the class path, which (in development terms) starts from the src. So if your file is in a `src/resources/file.txt`, then you'd use the path `"/resources/file.txt"`

Comment: - No I'm not using my file as a resource to your project but just for tests.
- I've putted my xls file in both of .java and .class files directories and still not working.
- My working directory is C:\NetBeansProjects\TestExcel\src

Comment: The working directory is the project root. So put the file in root directory ie `TestExcel\1.xls`. Then you can use just the name of the file as the path. If you put the file in the src, then you need to use the path `"src\1.xls"`